# how do I get random question from pool of questions

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-core-authorization

I have 50 random questions, 1, 2,3... 50..
I want to show 5 questions to user,
Let say user start, random 5 questions I need to show to user one by one.

Question should not repeat...

I am using .net core web api...

```
{
Math.Random...
}

In my question sometime it get duplicate question....means same question user getting again..


how can I manage this?
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a list.

Inside a loop that repeats 5 times:

- Take a random index from 0 to length of list
- Save the item in that position
- Remove it from the list

This way, it won't be in the list for the next loops.

Example code:

```
List<string> questions = ...; // Your question pool
Random rnd = new Random();

string[] selectedQuestions = {"", "", "", "", ""}; // Your 5 selected questions
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  int indx = rnd.Next(0, questions.Count);

  selectedQuestions[i] = questions[indx];
  questions.RemoveAt(indx);
}
```

Comment: @Startis.. Thank you.But here I am using .net core api so problem is in next request I may get another may be another request for same user can get chance to get same question. any suggestion on this.

Comment: Since you are using an API and my code will probably reset on each call, I suggest you save what questions the user has already answered. Like, create a table in your database with 2 columns, 1 for the userId and 1 for the questionId (if you have them in the database as an entity as well) or the question string itself. You can save it in any other way you want like a text file or anything, I just gave an example. Use that and pre-remove the already-answered-by-the-user questions from the list before the loop.